# can't start mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to start mongo db but I'm getting an error
  Here is the output:

```
k-ps-macbook:~ kp$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4143 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit 
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.2, pdfile version 4.5
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] git version: 433bbaa14aaba6860da15bd4de8edf600f56501b
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] build sys info: Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.0: Mon Nov 24 17:37:00 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.59~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] couldn't open /data/db/awesome_blog.ns errno:13 Permission denied
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] error couldn't open file /data/db/awesome_blog.ns terminating
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 dbexit: 
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Aug 16 15:57:11 dbexit: really exiting now
```

any help will be appreciated,
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need read/write permissions to /data/db/

Answer (score 1):

The error shows up, because you are not logged in as root user. To do that (if you use Debian), run:

```
sudo mongod
```

Or simply:

```
su root
```

Then type the password and type

```
mongod
```

Then you will get access to the
 /data/db directory.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted /data/db/mongod.lock to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, run:

1. cd ~
2. ./mongod --repair

If you're still having trouble getting it to run then find the /data directory (it should be inside of ~ or ~/workspace) and cd into it. Once inside, run rm mongod.lock then cd back into ~ and run ./mongod again (see below).

1. cd ~/data
2. rm mongod.lock
3. cd
4. ./mongod